# How to create a collapsing 3columns layout width bootstrap 2.3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

my goal is a responsive layout with fixed column-width (for tablets and desktops) to achieve 3 columns for desktops, 2 columns for tablets and 1 column for phones.
Unfortunately, the width of the "768"-container is calculated by using the grid and glutter widths.

Is there any way to say "hey, the 768-container should only be 700px" without changing the responsive*.less files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this without LESS changes would be to use a @media query..

For example, if you're using `.span4` to get 3 columns across, you can use CSS to override Bootstrap's width of the `.span4` on tablets:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .row .span4 {width:46%;}
}
```

**Demo with @media queries: http://www.bootply.com/64864**

Another way is using the responsive utility classes. This method involves more HTML markup, but the layout is easier. For example, here 3 `span4` are displyed for desktop, and 2 `span6` are displayed for tablet. For phone the `span6` switch to 100% to display 1 column.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row visible-desktop hidden-tablet hidden-phone">
      <div class="span4">..</div>
      <div class="span4">..</div>
      <div class="span4">..</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row hidden-desktop visible-tablet">
      <div class="span6">..</div>
      <div class="span6">..</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Demo with utility classes: http://www.bootply.com/64868**